# Having Trouble Installing/Using Packages with Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, spyder, python-module

I am very new to Python and have reviewed multiple questions here on problems getting packages/modules to import but can't seem to work out what I'm doing wrong. I'm simply trying to import packages and use them in the Spyder console, I'm used to working in R Studio so that's kind of my point of reference.

I run the below code and receive the following messages.

```
pip install Pillow
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (7.0.0)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

import Pillow
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-f4cbff62aba7>", line 1, in <module>
    import Pillow

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pillow'
```

I also seem to be getting different results when I run pip install from the console vs from the text editor portion. When I run it from the console, I get the above result about it already being installed. When I run it from the text editor portion, I get the following.

```
runcell(0, 'C:/Users/name/.spyder-py3/temp.py')
  File "C:\Users\name\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 1
    pip install Pillow
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You import Pillow by writing `import PIL` , and not `import Pillow` , furthermore, you cannot install modules using `pip` inside a `.py` file, this is not a python command.

Comment: Oh well that works. Is there a common format for the shorthand of package names in python or is it always just first three letters or something?

Comment: No common shorthand that I know about, you can always check out pypi: https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/2.2.1/